# Console o/p to text file

Tags: text-files

```
namespace WhileLoop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("\nEnter name of the participant (Quit to quit): ");
               String name = Console.ReadLine();
                //Console.Write("Enter the telephone number of the participant: ");
                //int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            while (name != "quit")
            {
                //String name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter the telephone number of the participant: ");
                int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("\nEnter name of the participant (Quit to quit): ");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("Conference1.txt", FileMode.Create);
                TextWriter tmp = Console.Out;
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                Console.SetOut(sw);
                Console.WriteLine(name,number); 
                Console.SetOut(tmp);
                sw.Close();


            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Iam trying the save the input I entered for name and telephone to be saved in a file called conference1.text. But only the last name (quit) is only saved in the txt file. How do I save all the input I entered in the txt file?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the file mode you're specifying:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("Conference1.txt", FileMode.Create);
```

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. **If the file already exists, it will be overwritten**.

If you want to *append* to the file, you might try `FileMode.Append` instead.  Additionally, if you don't need the file to be appended in real-time, you can store all of the input values in a list and then write the list to the file after the loop.  (That way you're not opening/writing/closing the file over and over, which is a lot of I/O.)